# store from list string to another array list

Tags: java

I have a txt file like this which contains longitude and latitude coords:

```
120.12    22.233
100    23.12
98     19.12
```

If I want to read the file, I am doing:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
System.out.println("LINE: " + lines.get(0));
```

and it gives me :  `120    22`

I have a class that reads latitude and longitude:

```
public class GisPoints {

    private double lat;
    private double lon;

    public GisPoints() {
    }

    public GisPoints(double lat, double lon) {
       super();
       this.lat = lat;
       this.lon = lon;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I want to store all the values from the txt file into an `List<GisPoints>`.

So, I want a function in order to load file:

```
public static List<GisPoints> loadData(String fileName) throws IOException {

      List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));

      List<GisPoints> points = new ArrayList<GisPoints>();

      //for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {

     // }

      return points;

  }
```

As I said, right now I am just reading every line, for example `lines[0] = 120   22`

I want to store lines[0] longitude into points[0].setLon(), lines[0] latitude into points[0].setLat().

Comment: [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: *what have you tried already?*

Comment: since your file contains only ints, you can use nextInt method in Scanner class

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie:It will not contain only ints

Comment: either way if a longitude and latitude can be identified in a certain line, Scanner would be a better choice

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Why OP need scanner as he already read the file and got lines ? I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @SureshAtta I didn't say he need to, I said its a better choice since he can access the content of the lines and store ints individually instead of manipulation a String. Does that make since ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        String line = lines.get(i);

        String[] values = line.split("\\s+");

        double lat = Double.parseDouble(values[0]);
        double lon = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);

        points.add(new GisPoints(lat, lon));
    }
```

Comment: It shows: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-117.1"`.I am trying to use `-117.1    32.533`

Comment: Now, if I print `points`, it gives me the package name `mylib.gispoint.GisPoints@262a8f13, mylib.gispoints.GisPoints@22150f0e,....`

Comment: @George you have to override the `toString()` method in your `GisPoints` class

Comment: @George Or get the values through the getter-methods in GisPoint and print it then.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy solution with String.split()

```
private GisPoints createGisPointsObjectFromLine(String p_line)
{
    String[] split = p_line.trim().split(" ");
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
    double lon = Double.parseDouble(split[split.length - 1]);
    return GisPoints(lat, lon);
}
```

You can call this method from your loadData() method.
I hope this solution is helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String str : lines) {
    String[] helpArray = str.split("\\s+"); // or whatever is betweeen
                                            // the two numbers
    points.add(new GisPoints(Double.valueOf(helpArray[0].trim()), Double.valueOf(helpArray[1].trim())));
}
```

this should work as you need it. only works as long as there are only numbers in the file. you can report back if you need further help

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store lines[0] longitude into points[0].setLon(), lines[0] latitude into points[0].setLat().

You don't need setters right away. You have a good constructor to receive both of them already.

Just create an object after splitting like into two parts.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) { 
      String[] latlang = lines.get(i).split("\\s+");
      GisPoints g = new GisPoints(Double.parseDouble(latlang[0].trim()),Double.parseDouble(latlang[1].trim()));
      points.add(g)
    }
```

Comment: you forgot the splitting i guess :)

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy Oh no. You saved me :D

Answer (score 1):

I think `split` can solve your problem:

```
String arr[] = lines[i].split("\\s+");
GisPoints p = new GisPoints(Double.parseDouble(arr[0]), Double.parseDouble(arr[1]));
```

Comment: `arr[0]` is String. Not double.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do it with java8-streams:

```
 List<GisPoint> points = lines.stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
        .map(array -> Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(String::trim)
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .toArray()
        )
        .map(array -> new GisPoint(array[0], array[1]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you should `.trim()` the array values

Comment: @XtremeBaumer what about now?

Comment: @Lino:It shows `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-117.1 32.5333333333333"`, if I use these numbers in the file

Comment: @Lino:yes, i have

Comment: you have 1 string with 2 numbers which can never be converted. try splitting with `\\s+`

Comment: strange... seems like i've used different data for testing, because on my machine its running

Comment: @Lino:Now, if I print points, it gives me the package name mylib.gispoint.GisPoints@262a8f13, mylib.gispoints.GisPoints@22150f0e,....

Comment: yes that is because my implementation returns a list of GisPoints, is that not required?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the class Scanner; Scanner has a lot of useful tools for reading and parsing strings.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but not a complete answer. This would be best as a comment (of course if you intend to improve it that's alright I guess)

Comment: You can add some code snippet useful to OP ..else it should be a comment

Comment: I must have 50 reputation to comment on questions, which i don't. This is an assignment i think he or she could figure out by himself and thereby i didn't elaborate more, merely pointed him or her in the right direction. Rest assured, if i had 50 rep this would have been simply a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look with regex :

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String line = "98 19";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)\\s*(\\d+)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
        }
     }
}
```